# Oracle Gather Statistics after Partition Exchange

Tags: oracle12c

Database: Oracle 12c

I have a process that selects data from Fact Table, summarizes it and push it to Summary Table.

Summary table is Range Partitioned (Trade Date) and List Partitioned (File Id).

the process picks up data from Fact table (where file_id=<> for all Trade Dates), summarizes it in a temp table and use Partition Exchange to move data from Temp table to one of the SubPartitions in Summary Table (as the process works on a File Id level).

Summary table is completely refreshed everyday (100% data will be exchanged).

Before the data is exchanged at the subpartition level, statistics are gathered and exchanged along with the data.

After the process is completed, we run dbms_gather_table_stats at partition level (in a for loop - for each partition) with granularity set as "approx_global and partition".

Even though we collect stats at the global level, user_tab_statistics for the summary table has "STALE_STATS" = YES for this table, however, partition & Subpartition stats are available.

when we run a query against the summary table (for a date range of 3 years), the query spins for a long time - spiking the CPU to 90%, but never returns any data.

I checked the explain plan on the query, Cardinality is showing as 1.

I read about incremental stats, but it seems increment will work if a few partitions change - it may not be the best option in my case, where data across all the partitions change completely.

I m looking for a strategy to gather statistics on the summary table - don't want to run a full gather stats.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm afraid your question is a little off-topic here. Please ask it on [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) - but it's a nice question anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I'll move it over.

Comment: I think the issue is whether incremental stats are supported at the sub-partition level.

Comment: @BobC: we do have stats available at sub-partition and partition level. Table stats are stale because more than 10% of data is modified at the table level. I tested the table with incremental set to Yes. Gather table stats job started collecting stats for the sub-partitions as well - the process was very slow and we don;t have a lot of time in the overnight batch cycle.

Comment: As i suspected, incremental stats are not supported for sub-partitions. It might be worth just reviewing your processes flow and partitioning strategy; I'm happy to discuss it with you, if you can figure out how to move the topic to a discussion :)

Comment: Thanks BobC. As I mentioned in my original post, stats are already available at the sub-partition level. I ran gather table stats and set the granularity as PARTITION and that resolved all the partition stats (the job ran for about 20 minutes) and then I tried running gather table stats and set the granularity as GLOBAL and that resolved the table level Stats. At this point I don't see any STALE_STATS in USER_TAB_STATISTICS. I tried the Insert Query and it ran in 33 seconds. I m testing an alternative strategy by locking the stats at the table level. will keep the group posted.

Comment: we tried locking the table stats and run partition exchange, but it didn't work as expected. Table level stats became stale again. However the following worked for us. 1. Run the process for full Summarization 2. Compute sub-partition level stats, include it as part of Partition Exchange 3.Run Gather table stats at Partition Level (Granularity set as PARTITION) 4.After Partition Stats are completed. Gather table stats (Granularity set as GLOBAL)

Comment: @BobC: I don't know how to move this to a discussion.  still learning the tricks in Stackoverflow.

Comment: It seems that we just have to keep commenting and it will eventually ask us to move to chat :)